# iOS -- When to create a child ViewController vs. a UIView Subclass?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Maybe this is a silly question, but I've bumped into it a number of times during iOS Development.

Sometimes I'll develop a view component that I want to use on multiple screens, so I'll decide to subclass `UIView` and make it something I can use in multiple places.

Then, I start adding functionality to it.  Maybe it needs to respond to an `NSNotification`, or it is supposed to respond to user touches.

At a certain point, I start wondering if I should really be making a `UIViewController` subclass, and add it to my UI as a child ViewController.

Is there any consensus on where to draw the line between adding some behaviors to a `UIView`, and when to create a full `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a controller anytime that you need to handle or control data. Views are supposed to be as stupid as possible, not knowing what they are displaying but rather where. You can easily subclass and reuse ViewControllers. A good example, say you need to retrieve a string (or text) from the user throughout your app via a popover controller and a modal. Create a generic subclass of `UIViewController` that has a view with a textfield and a button. You can then use this view and it's controller in any capacity you need. Reusing it in the popover, modal or anywhere else (and generally passing the data back through delegation). Since you are dealing with data you should not being using a sole subclass of UIView.

From my experience I subclass `UIViewControllers` more often then `UIViews`. It is a little difficult for me to understand if you are solely talking about Containers or reuse of views in general application workflow. Either way though it should be the same.

Comment: Beautiful.  That's always been my inclination as well.

Comment: The case that prompted me to post this was actually for something that won't be re-used.. it's very specific to a specific screen.   However,  the component has a lot of plumbing, and it really felt like it needed better separation from ViewController is was included in.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. Subclassing a UIViewController for a specific situation is not a bad idea, but attempt to make them as generic as possible. Like in my example do not name it `ColorNameCollector` or something because then it can only be used to get colors. Rather name it something like `StringCollector`. This way it is more generic and can be used whenever you need to get a string from the user, regardless of where or how it is presented/used.

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you about the consensus, but here's my opinion:

Subclass `UIView` only when...

- You want to do custom drawing
- You need to customize some behaviour of an already existing `UIView` subclass
- You have special needs for layouting subviews. Most layouting can be done by `UIViewController`, though.
- Maybe for special touch handling that you can't be done with gesture recognizers

Subclass `UIViewController` in all other cases. You almost always need a controller anyway, for writing glue code that ties together views and models, or for handling user interaction. Consequently, Apple has made it easy in UIKit to let controllers do all the work and to keep views as "stupid" as possible. For instance, it is very simple to nest controllers to create complex view hierarchies, without the need to have a single view subclass.

An indicator that subclassing `UIView` is not the first thing one should do is the section titled "Alternatives to Subclassing" in the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). An indicator that subclassing `UIViewController` is the preferred thing to do is that there is no such section in the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :-)

Comment: @herzbube do you think that's why we now have container view with child VCs in IB? Is this the way to go to share parts of our UI between scenes (like a profile picture + name + status dot)?

Comment: @allaire Comments are not really useful for discussions, nor are they intended to be so. You could maybe start this discussion in a chat channel to get an opinion. That being said, I admit that 1) I have never used IB much; 2) I have been rather disconnected from iOS development for several months now, so I don't really know what IB is giving to devs these days, and how Apple thinks it should be used. Maybe watch a tech video or two?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the embedded view controllers to load reusable table views from time to time. I've found that it's useful sometimes but not always. Communication between the two can be cumbersome, like if you want the embedded controller to communicate back up to the container. Delegation makes it easier but still cumbersome. It also limits you to iOS 6, if I remember right iOS 5 and lower don't support embedded controllers.

If it's just adding methods you can use a category to store some extra methods. I do that a lot on NSManagedObjects that I don't want to subclass and if I regenerate the NSManagedObject from the datamodel I don't lose the code in my categories. Gives me added functionality like calculated fields or conversion methods without having to subclass. If you don't need those methods for a particular instance just exclude the reference to the category.

Subclassing never is bad though IMO.